# How to close a disconnected jdbc connection?

Tags: java, ojdbc

I am setting up a connection between two servers (One running a jdbc application and second running an oracle DB) using jdbc to query few tables.

Since these servers reside in two different countries, sometimes there is a disconnect between the two servers.

When the connection is not established due to `IO Error: Network adapter could not establish the connection`, the app can retry-establish the connection. But once a conn is established, and then there is a disconnect, the application just hangs and doesn't Timeout or come out of the connection.

Can anybody please help me out to close or exit such connections ?

Comment: try using a DBCP

Comment: What kind of timeouts have you configured?

Comment: Which database driver/version is it?

Comment: @Kayaman, currently no timeout are explicitly mentioned in the connection call. Would adding "connection.setNetworkTimeout(executor, milliseconds);" help to exit the DB call ?

Comment: @gusto2 It's an OJDBC-14

Comment: @sarthak I wouldn't expect them to be explicitly specified. You'll need to find the configuration and set a suitable read/connect timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement

```
String user = "user";
String password = "password";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name";
try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table;");
) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        // TODO
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: The question isn't about closing a connection, it's about a connection being closed due to a network error.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in the `finally` block to ensure that the connection is closed in case of both success and exception. 
Example code is shared below for your reference.

```
import java.sql.*;  
class MysqlConnectionExample{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName";
        String userName = "userName";
        String password = "password";
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        Connection con= null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try{  
            // Create connection
            Class.forName(driverName);  
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, userName, password);  
            stmt = con.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee");  

            // Iterate over the results
            while(rs.next()) { 
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            System.out.println(e);
        }  
        finally{
            // Close connection
            con.close();
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Rohit, but I actually wanted to understand that if there a disconnection between the sttmt "ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee");" and "while(rs.next()) { ", jdbc doesn't return anything and gets hung. So is there a way to timeout the "stmt.executeQuery" ?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you can provide a timeout in the statement like this:
`stmt.setQueryTimeout(60); // for timeout limit = 60 seconds`

This has been explained very well on this page.
[link](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-set-the-query-timeout-limit/)

Answer (score -1):

if you use connection fool, i think it's will be like youre situation. As other answers, i recommend to use 'connection.close()'; 
 and it needed, it's better to add 'trasation' scope.

Comment: connection.close() does a clean close, but what I wanted to know was between the executeQuery() and Resultset return if there is a disconnection, then jdbc basically gets hung and as a result the whole application. Is there a way to timeout my executeQuery() sttmnt even though connection is lost ?